# IF-ELSE inside of a SELECT Query

Tags: sql-server

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
SELECT
TBL1.Name,
TBL2.ID,
(
    IF TBL2.ID = 'X'
    SELECT TBL3.Addr
    FROM TBL3
    WHERE TBL3.ID = TBL2.ID
    ELSE
    SELECT TBL4.Room
    FROM TBL4
    WHERE TBL4.ID = TBL2.ID
)
AS Location
FROM TBL1
INNER JOIN TBL2
ON TBL1.ID = TBL2.ID
INNER JOIN TBL3
ON TBL2.ID = TBL3.ID
```

From the above code you can see something like what I am trying to do. I just want to select from two different tables depending on if TBL2.ID is 'X' or 'Rm' or 'St' etc. If I can get this working I can worry about the other values later.

What I have tried (just going to post the piece between the () which I am having problem with):

```
(
    SELECT CASE
    WHEN TBL2.ID = 'X'
    THEN
    SELECT TBL3.Addr FROM TBL3 WHERE TBL3.ID = TBL2.ID
    ELSE
    SELECT TBL4.Room FROM TBL4 WHERE TBL4.ID = TBL2.ID
    END
) AS Location
```

This gives errors:
The multi-part identifier "TBL2.ID" could not be bound.
Incorrect syntax near 'SELECT'.

**Question:** How to write if-else statement / case statement inside another select query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If either `TBL3.Addr` or `TBL4.Room` is available and the other is always missing then consider doing this instead:

```
SELECT
    TBL1.Name,
    TBL2.ID,
    COALESCE(TBL3.Addr, TBL4.Room) AS Location
FROM
    TBL1
    INNER JOIN TBL2
        ON TBL1.ID = TBL2.ID
    LEFT JOIN TBL3
        ON TBL2.ID = TBL3.ID
    LEFT JOIN TBL4
        ON TBL2.ID = TBL4.ID
```

See: [COALESCE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

`case statement` will return a `scalar value` you cannot write a `select` inside case statement. Move your `TBL4` to `Join` Try this instead.

```
SELECT
TBL1.Name,
TBL2.ID,
case when TBL2.ID = 'X' then TBL3.Addr else TBL4.Room end AS Location
FROM TBL1
INNER JOIN TBL2
ON TBL1.ID = TBL2.ID
INNER JOIN TBL3
ON TBL2.ID = TBL3.ID
inner join TBL4 on TBL4.ID = TBL2.ID
```

Comment: The problem with that is I can't inner join TBL4 because the IDs that don't exist on all the tables are being cut off. I went from 1400 rows to 1100 rows. I just need TBL4 to catch the additional IDs.

Answer (score 1):

Just reference the column name from the `CASE` statement

```
SELECT
TBL1.Name,
TBL2.ID,
(
    CASE WHEN TBL2.ID = 'X' THEN 
      TBL3.Addr
    ELSE
      TBL4.Room
    END
)
AS Location
FROM TBL1
INNER JOIN TBL2 ON TBL1.ID = TBL2.ID
INNER JOIN TBL3 ON TBL2.ID = TBL3.ID
INNER/LEFT JOIN TBL4 ON TBL2.ID = TBL4.ID
```